# Subclassing existing custom UITableViewCell + XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` called `StandardTableViewCell`. This is made in a XIB with autolayout.
The cell is registered with the method `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`

What I am trying to do now is subclass `StandardTableViewCell` without making a new XIB.

Is it possible to reuse the cell without making a new XIB while keeping the cell's  `File Owner`?

Comment: Have you thought of creating a category instead of subclassing? Not sure what you're exactly doing, but that might work instead.

Comment: I just tried it, but I am having trouble with the setSelected:animated: method because I'm overriding it.

Comment: Ok, might not work that way then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of creating a category instead of subclassing? Not sure what you're exactly doing, but that might work instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible, so you have to use a less than ideal solution, here's some options:

Implement the functionality in the same Standard cell and toggle it.
Duplicate the standard nib and replace the cell class.
Don't have a standard nib and just make one for each subclass (if they are different this is probably the best idea).